# How are you meant to redirect WatchKit app users to directions in the Maps app?

Tags: mapkit, watchkit, watchos-2

Reading the documentation, there are two ways I assumed I could do this.

The first is with [the Apple Maps URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1) because the documentation claims "you can use map links to open that information in the Maps app in iOS, OS X, or watchOS 2 and later". I tried building a maps URL myself and passing it to -[WKExtension openSystemURL:], despite the documentation saying the method only handles *tel:* and *sms:* URLs, because it was the only way I was aware of to open a URL on watchOS 2. That didn't end up working.

After further investigation, I discovered that [MKMapItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MKMapItem/openMapsWithItems:launchOptions) has an *openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:* method that I could call. I built a map item from a placemark, called it with the directions mode set to any of the three directions modes, and nothing happens when I call it. I looked at both my placemark and map item in the debugger, and they seemed to have gotten initialized just fine.

The Location and Maps Programming Guide states that you must enable maps in the Capabilities tab of a target in Xcode to have MapKit functionality work, so I tried that as well, and neither option worked.

I'm at a loss as to what I'm supposed to do. I know it's supposed to be possible because the Workflow application does it, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In the WatchOS 2 release notes it is stated:

> The MKMapItem method openInMapsWithLaunchOptions: does not work.

Link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/releasenotes/General/RN-watchOSSDK-2.0/index.html

You could use a WKInterfaceMap and add an annotation to it. 
If the user clicks on it he will be directed to the maps app and routing can be started. Swift example:

```
let mapLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
let coordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1);

self.map.addAnnotation(mapLocation, withPinColor: WKInterfaceMapPinColor.Green)
self.map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapLocation, span: coordinateSpan))
```